# Compiling openssh-3.6.1p2 fails

Tags: linux, openssh

I am trying to install `openssh-3.6.1p2` on `Debian 8.6`

`./configure` without problems, but when `./make`

I get error(http://pastebin.com/i8C7mYMa). Could anyone give me advice how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Why are you trying to compile an OpenSSH version from 2004? and 2) For OpenSSH bugs, try [here](https://www.openssh.com/report.html) first.

Comment: I am preparing security scenario, and I need version from 2004 because it has vulnerability, I try OpenSSH problem reports, thanks.